# What are the key components in angular 15+, how does it work exactly?

Tags: angular, frontend

I'm new to angular. I have explored and reached out to angular and got some practice from the angular homepage.
Newbies like me are also quite confused about the architecture of the new technology and how it makes the final product reach the user.
As the title says, what are the main components of angular and how exactly does it work?

I have consulted on many websites, but there is no exact, consistent and reliable answer. Some say 4 components (Component, Template, Directives , DI) while some say 5 or even 6.

I'm pretty confused by this